# Problem with a bootstrap 4 class and fa search icon not rendering as I would like

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I having trouble with a nav I'm setting up... I would like for my form to have a width of 100 and for the append button to show a search icon. Neither is rendering correctly. Maybe a second pair of eyes can point me in the right direction?

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<form class="" class="form-inline w-100">
  <div class="input-group w-100">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="dropdown show">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="category-list" data-toggle="dropdown">All</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Laptop</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Electronics</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Other</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-main"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the Drop down menu area about?

Comment: The icons should be using Material Icons and not FontAwesome: <span class="material-icons">
search
</span>

Comment: I suggest you have a look at https://fonts.google.com/icons. You can't just use Font Awesome classes with any ol' font library.

Comment: You didn't load FontAwesome CSS.